# Chinese characters appear in attribute table

Tags: qgis, mac, internationalization

I am running QGIS 2.4 on a mac, and all of the text in my attribute tables appears in Chinese.  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, changing the locale to U.S. English, and nothing helps.  I've tried opening attribute tables in other applications, and they appear in English everywhere else, so the problem seems to be in importing them to QGIS.

Comment: Did you also install the required dependencies? If not, have a look here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: The encoding option is used the same source?

Comment: The `locale` setting is only for menu entries, with no effect on the data.

Answer (score 2):

Just another chance: `Settings -> Options -> DataSources` tab, check `Ignore shapefile encoding declaration`.

It might be necessary to restart QGIS and reload the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve this, when you open the shapefile in QGIS, choose macintosh where it says encoding